# location of gradle version in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

From where does the Android Studio picks the already downloaded gradle version ,There are three places where the gradle is visbile :

in the C:\Users\.gradle\caches\
in the C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\com\android\tools\build\gradle
or if provided in the gradle -wrapper properties of the project. : distributionUrl=file:///c:gradle-2.14.1-all.zip

Same from where the Android Studio picks up the Android Plugin Version : 
is it from C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\com\android\tools\build\gradle

I wanted to know these to build the project offline and need to copy these things from one PC to another.

Answer (score 1):

You can download gradle from https://gradle.org/install/

If you want to work offline extract it in your hard drive or you can also copy the files from caches.

Then follow these steps:

1. goto Files>Settings in Android Studio.
2. goto Build,Execution,Development>Gradle
3. choose your gradle path

See this image

[image]

Comment: This is gradle but what about the android plugin? From where can i copy it? Afaik only coresponding   Android plugin will work with the coresponding gradle version. Like gradle i can copy from .gradle cache but where is android plugin or is it under the same .gradle/cache/ dir and by copying .gradle/cache and .gradle it will work offline with above settings?

Comment: if you don't change the default location while installing Abdroid studio
check this path
C:\Users\Your.name\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1

Comment: go to Your Android Studio installation path -> plugins -> gradle -> probably its there, i can't find any version informatio of the gradle files saved there, but i think that coulde be the grade plugin location

Comment: or take a look here: `.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.tools.build\gradle`

Answer (score 0):

I think all version saved, are here:

```
C:\Users\Admin\.gradle

C:\Users\Admin\.gradle\caches
```